# Java STM: Questions on Multiverse STM

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, stm

I am performing some research into STM technologies on the JVM. Having read some documents, I am a little confused about Multiverse's implementation.

According to [the Multiverse FAQ](http://multiverse.codehaus.org/faq.html#question.1), Multiverse does not support instrumentation. However, in an interview with its founder Peter Veentjer, he has the following to say:

> One of the mission statements of Multiverse is to provide an STM implementation that can easily be integrated with other languages, so the actual STM implementation only cares about interfaces, so you can bypass instrumentation completely. And to make it even more easy, I provided a managed reference that doesn't rely on instrumentation. This is the approach being used in the Scala based Akka project of Jonas Boner.

What exactly does this mean? Does it use byte code instrumentation or not?

Lastly, I've been reading another document [here](http://ppl.stanford.edu/papers/scaladays2010bronson.pdf) on ScalaSTM, and in this it clearly implies that Multiverse uses byte code instrumentation.

Therefore, I am wondering if someone can tell me a little about how Multiverse actually works.
Is it a runtime library similar to ScalaSTM, or does it use instrumentation?

Comment: https://github.com/pveentjer/Multiverse